# shuffle only 5 of 20 random items of an html list (see the code)

Tags: javascript

good morning and thanks in advance to the whole community for this magnificent support. Who can help me to improveI a function to this code to return only 5 elements randomly from the entire list of 20 elements. I enter the code that now shows randomly the entire list.  Thanks to the whole community...

```js
var list = document.getElementById("items"),
newlist = document.getElementById("shuffle");
function shuffle(items)
{
    var cached = items.slice(0), temp, i = cached.length, rand;
    while(--i)
    {
        rand = Math.floor(i * Math.random());
        temp = cached[rand];
        cached[rand] = cached[i];
        cached[i] = temp;
    }
    return cached;
}
function shuffleNodes()
{
    var nodes = list.children, i = 0;
    nodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(nodes);
    nodes = shuffle(nodes);
    while(i < nodes.length)
    {
        list.appendChild(nodes[i]);
        ++i;
    }
}
window.onload = shuffleNodes;
```

```html
<form id="something">
<div class="classname">
    
<dl id="items">
    <dd>1. item.<br></dd>
    <dd>2. item.<br></dd>
    <dd>3. item.<br></dd>
    <dd>4. item.<br></dd>
    <dd>5. item.<br></dd>
    <dd>6. item.<br></dd>
    <dd>7. item.<br></dd>
    <dd>8. item.<br></dd>
    <dd>9. item.<br></dd>
    <dd>10. item.<br></dd>
    <dd>11. item.<br></dd>
    <dd>12. item.<br></dd>
    <dd>13. item.<br></dd>
    <dd>14. item.<br></dd>
    <dd>15. item.<br></dd>
    <dd>16. item.<br></dd>
    <dd>17. item.<br></dd>
    <dd>18. item.<br></dd>
    <dd>19. item.<br></dd>
    <dd>20. item.<br></dd>
</dl>

</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stay only 5 shuffled elements on the screen you should modify your shuffleNodes() by clearing the list and adding 5 elements in while loop as follows:

```
function shuffleNodes()
{
    var nodes = list.children, i = 0;
    nodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(nodes);
    nodes = shuffle(nodes);
    
    list.innerHTML = "";
  
    while(i < 5)
    {
        list.appendChild(nodes[i]);
        ++i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Agree, but list at the beginning contains 20 elements, declared directly in HTML. If he wants to have only shuffled numbers on the screen, then its good to clear the list before adding shuffled numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Good Morning, and thanks for the code! could you give me one last help? I'm trying but I can not divide this list (total 20 items); select random elements; Mix:
2 elements (between 0.10) and 2 elements (between 10.20) and show everything randomly when the page loads...  in the snipped the list is divided (between 0 and 10) and the first 2 elements are selected....

```js
var list = document.getElementById("items"),
newlist = document.getElementById("shuffle");
function shuffle(items)
{
    var cached = items.slice(0,10), temp, i = cached.length, rand;
    while(--i)
    {
        rand = Math.floor(i * Math.random());
        temp = cached[rand];
        cached[rand] = cached[i];
        cached[i] = temp;
    }
    return cached;
}
function shuffleNodes()
{
    var nodes = list.children, i = 0;
    nodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(nodes);
    nodes = shuffle(nodes);
    
    list.innerHTML = "";
  
    while(i < 2)
    {
        list.appendChild(nodes[i]);
        ++i;
    }
}
window.onload = shuffleNodes;
```

```html
<form id="something">
<div class="classname">
    
<dl id="items">
    <dd>1. item.<br></dd>
    <dd>2. item.<br></dd>
    <dd>3. item.<br></dd>
    <dd>4. item.<br></dd>
    <dd>5. item.<br></dd>
    <dd>6. item.<br></dd>
    <dd>7. item.<br></dd>
    <dd>8. item.<br></dd>
    <dd>9. item.<br></dd>
    <dd>10. item.<br></dd>
    <dd>11. item.<br></dd>
    <dd>12. item.<br></dd>
    <dd>13. item.<br></dd>
    <dd>14. item.<br></dd>
    <dd>15. item.<br></dd>
    <dd>16. item.<br></dd>
    <dd>17. item.<br></dd>
    <dd>18. item.<br></dd>
    <dd>19. item.<br></dd>
    <dd>20. item.<br></dd>
</dl>

</div>
</form>
```